# Dynamically create on object of type C++

Tags: c++

I have a method which returns pointer of one of three relative classes:

```
Base* Base::search_by_name(string name) {
    children_iterator = children.begin();
    while (children_iterator != children.end()) {
        if (name == (*children_iterator)->getName()) {
            switch ((*children_iterator)->class_number) {
            case 1: return ((Derived*)*children_iterator);
            case 2: return ((Derived2*)*children_iterator);
            case 3: return ((Derived3*)*children_iterator);
            }
```

And I need to create an object exactly of the class, which class` pointer method returns

```
     bool Base::set_connection(int number, string& process_object) {
        typeid(root->search_by_name(process_object)) myobject; // Derived myobject, Derived2 myobject or Derived3 myobject
        if (myobject != NULL) {
            string signal = this->getName();
            myobject->get_connection (number, signal); //each class has its own realisation of get_connection
```

I tryed the line `typeid(root->search_by_name(process_object)) myobject;`But it`s obviously silly. Could you advise something?

Comment: You can try using a `void` pointer and later typecast it accordingly. Not a clean solution  though.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to derive the *static type* of the *polymorphic* object so as to make a *static declaration* of type as in:

```
my_static_type object;
```

There are a couple of things you could do.

One is to put a `clone()` or `create()` style function in your *polymorphic* classes to return correctly typed *dynamic objects*.

```
BaseClass* n = root->search_by_name(process_object)->create(); // new object
```

The other would be to manually query the possible types, which rather defeats the point of *polymorphism*:

```
auto* p = root->search_by_name(process_object);

BaseClass* b;

if(auto* n = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(p))
   b = new Derived;
else if(auto* n = dynamic_cast<Derived2*>(p))
   b = new Derived2;
else
    throw std::runtime_error("problems problems");
```

**NOTE:** Pointers used for exposition only, use `std::unique_ptr` etc.. in real code.